# Best Approach to separate Form sections

Tags: html, razor

I have the following view inside my Asp.net MVC web application :-

```
p class="b"> <i class="icon-th"></i>Network Info :</p>

<div>
<span class="f">IP Address</span> 

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NetworkInfo.IPADDRESS)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NetworkInfo.IPADDRESS)                                              
 | 
   <input type="CheckBox" name="IsIPUnique" value="true" @(Html.Raw(Model.IsIPUnique ? "checked=\"checked\"" : ""))/> IP Unique. 

</div>

<div >
<span class="f">MAC Address</span> 

  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NetworkInfo.MACADDRESS)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NetworkInfo.MACADDRESS) | 
    <input type="CheckBox" name="IsMACUnique" value="true" @(Html.Raw(Model.IsMACUnique ? "checked=\"checked\"" : ""))/> MAC Unique. 

</div>


<div >
  <span class="f">  ILOIP</span>

    @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.Server.ILOIP)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Server.ILOIP)
</div>


</p>
<p = class="b"><i class="icon-th"></i>Server Status :</p>

<div>
<span class="f">Server Status </span>

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.Server.StatusID, ((IEnumerable<TMS.Models.TechnologyStatu>)ViewBag.TechStatus).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
        Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Name), 
        Value = option.TechnologyStatusID.ToString(),
        Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.Server != null) && (option.TechnologyStatusID == Model.Server.StatusID)
    }), "Choose...")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Server.StatusID)
</div>

<div>
    <span class="f">Server Back Up Status</span>

   @Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.Server.BackUpStatusID, ((IEnumerable<TMS.Models.TechnologyBackUpStatu>)ViewBag.TechBackUpStatus).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
        Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Name), 
        Value = option.TechnologyBackUpStatusID.ToString(),
        Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.Server != null) && (option.TechnologyBackUpStatusID == Model.Server.BackUpStatusID)
    }), "Choose...")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Server.BackUpStatusID)
</div>
```

I tried to put each section header in a separate `<p>`, but the output was not very use-friendly. so which approach i can follow to separate each paragraph , so the user can understand each section fields better. as in the current output all the fields will be under each other without having space between each section?

Comment: why not google the following html tags: fieldset,legend,label

Comment: fieldset is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a question about MVC or Razor, but about HTML and CSS styling.  And for that you have a lot of options:

- You currently wrap all of your fields in `div` elements.  You could style those `div` elements however you like.  If you want to add vertical padding, you can use something like `padding-top: 20px;` or whatever ends up looking like you want it to look.
- You said you tried a `p` element.  This isn't really "paragraph" data, but the same concept as the `div` element applies.  You can style it however you like.
- You could wrap the fields in a `fieldset` element.  Remember that this requires a `legend` element as its first child element, which could contain a heading for that grouping of fields.  (Which would probably replace those `span` elements you currently use.)  There's a good chance that the default styling for your MVC project has considerations for `fieldset` already in the CSS.

You may also want to consider using `@Html.LabelFor()` while styling this as well, to provide field-level labels.  But it's hard to tell if you need that for the effect you're trying to achieve.  Normally a default form would have a `fieldset` with a `legend` and then a series of `label`s and `input`s therein.

The options could go on and on.  The point is that you're working with HTML and CSS at this point, so you'll want to show the client-side code and perhaps either a screen shot or live example of what you're trying, how you expect it to look, and how it's not working as expected.  That is, after you've tried tinkering with the styling of course.